# Fubini-Study in spherical coordinates.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-space

Is it possible to write the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ in terms of spherical coordinates?
How does such a metric look like?

Comment: What do you mean by spherical coordinates?

Comment: I mean the 4 real angular coordinates appearing in the round metric of $S^4$

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain how you intend to use coordinates on $S^4$ for the complex projective plane?

Comment: Consider the second line of equation (4,4) here.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.1053.pdf
This is claimed to be the Fubini-Study metric, written in terms of 4 angular coordinates $\sigma$, $\theta$, $\phi$, $\beta$.

My question is what is exactly the change of coordinates which brings the the Fubini Study metric defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric, and those 4 real angular coordinates.

Comment: The change of coordinates is a bit involved, since you have to take into account the projective nature of your space. In particular, I'll do the example with $\mathbb{CP}^1$. The change of coordinates it's the stereographic projection, more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric#The_n_.3D_1_case